# .htaccess redirect all links with */f_name1/* to */f_name2/*, no matter which uri-level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

in the controller(routing of requests) i rename folder **f_name1** to **f_name2**. 
To match this replace, i need to catch ALL urls and redirect appropriately.

Following structure is given, so the f_name1 can be in DIFFERENT levels of the url

> ```
> http://example.com/f_name1/hab/anot/ne/style.css (level1)
> http://example.com/js/f_name1/nofrac/script.js (level2)
> http://example.com/lev1/lev2/f_name1/lev4/lev5/lev6 (level3)
> ```

It should also redirect the queries (?var1=2)

what i started with is:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$/f_name2/(.*)$ $1/f_name1/$2 [P]
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Any hints, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bad effort when you don't know PCRE. This ensures it will only match a whole level, read [this explanation](https://regex101.com/r/45utAk/1) to understand what the symbols mean.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?fname_1(/.*)?$  $1fname_2$2 [L,R=301]
```